# Url routing Access denied at hosting

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I'm using url routing in my asp.net website.I  put colde in glocal.asax Application_Start event ,  void

```
Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("routedetail",
      "alllist/special/{Name}",
      "~/sub/mydetail.aspx");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("routelist",
            "alllist/special",
            "~/sub/mylist.aspx");


        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("routehtml", "alllist/myhtml.html", "~/sub/to.aspx");
    }
```

Every thing is ok in my local development and iis7.The error is at online hosting
"routehtml" is not work.Access denied occour.Is it for .html extension ?How can i solved this problem.any suggession..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting that into global.asax

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
   if(app.Request.Path.IndexOf("FriendlyPage.html") > 0)
   {
       app.Context.RewritePath("/UnfriendlyPage.aspx?SomeQuery=12345");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that your IIS 7 Application Pool is in Integrated mode on your host server. It will not work if it isn't.
Although you wouldn't need it, but you could also set RouteExistingFiles property to false at the top of your Application_Start event.